# Sorting a Pandas Pivot Containing Strings

Tags: python-2.7, sorting, pandas, pivot

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` which contains numeric values, date values, and text values. Something like this:

```
    Strike  StrikeCell                                      Expiration  ExpirationCell                                  CellContents
0   60.0    \n <div class="cell row-header strike itm" ...  2016-07-15  \n <div class="cell col-header expiration">...  \n <div class="cell option" strike="60.0" m...
1   60.0    \n <div class="cell row-header strike itm" ...  2017-01-20  \n <div class="cell col-header expiration">...  \n <div class="cell option" strike="60.0" m...
2   60.0    \n <div class="cell row-header strike itm" ...  2018-01-19  \n <div class="cell col-header expiration">...  \n <div class="cell option" strike="60.0" 
13  70.0    \n <div class="cell row-header strike itm" ...  2017-01-20  \n <div class="cell col-header expiration">...  \n <div class="cell option" strike="70.0" m...
15  70.0    \n <div class="cell row-header strike itm" ...  2018-01-19  \n <div class="cell col-header expiration">...  \n <div class="cell option" strike="70.0" m...
17  70.0    \n <div class="cell row-header strike itm" ...  2016-10-21  \n <div class="cell col-header expiration">...  \n <div class="cell option" strike="70.0" m...
...
562 260.0   \n <div class="cell row-header strike otm" ...  2017-01-20  \n <div class="cell col-header expiration">...  \n <div class="cell option" strike="260.0" ...
564 270.0   \n <div class="cell row-header strike otm" ...  2017-01-20  \n <div class="cell col-header expiration">...  \n <div class="cell option" strike="270.0" ...
565 280.0   \n <div class="cell row-header strike otm" ...  2017-01-20  \n <div class="cell col-header expiration">...  \n <div class="cell option" strike="280.0" ...
```

My intent is to have the `StrikeCell` down the first column (in ascending order), the `ExpirationCell` across the columns (in ascending order) and the `CellContents` as the values within the table. Basically I'm creating a large pivot table with html formatted contents.

I can do the following which works fine:

```
df.pivot(index='Strike', columns='Expiration', values='CellContents')
```

`Strike` is sorted correctly, the `Expiration` is sorted correctly.

However, if I try to use the string contents `StrikeCell` and `ExpirationCell` as follows:

```
df.pivot(index='StrikeCell', columns='ExpirationCell', values='CellContents')
```

the sorting is lost.

So the question is how to regain the ascending sort by `Strike` and `Expiration` while using the `StrikeCell` as `index` and `Expirationcell` as `columns`.

Using `pandas 0.18.1`.

Comment: It looks like for some other problem, because if use this test `df`, it sort correctly: `df = pd.DataFrame({'StrikeCell':['f','e','c','d','a','b'],
                   'ExpirationCell':['c','a','b','a','a','b'],
                   'CellContents':['a','b','c','a','a','b']})`

Comment: I noticed something like that too when testing. Anyone know the default sort?

Comment: I am not sure, but alphanumeric can be default sorting.

Comment: This should restore your initial ordering: `pivoted_df.reindex(index=df.StrikeCell, columns=df.ExpirationCell)`. HTH

Comment: Thanks but that did not solve it.

Comment: I think I misunderstood. Should `StrikeCell` keep the order of `Strike` sorted, and `ExpirationCell` - the order of sorted `Expiration`?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work for you.

First let's fix an order for `ExpirationCell` and `StrikeCell`.

```
StrikeCell_ordered = df[['Strike', 'StrikeCell']].sort_values(by='Strike')['StrikeCell']
ExpirationCell_ordered = df[['Expiration', 'ExpirationCell']].sort_values(by='Expiration')['ExpirationCell']
```

Then pivot and apply `reindex`:

```
pivoted_df = df.pivot(index='StrikeCell', columns='ExpirationCell', values='CellContents')
result = pivoted_df.reindex(index=StrikeCell_ordered, columns=ExpirationCell_ordered)
```

Comment: I had to add the `drop_duplicates` method to `StrikeCell_ordered` and `ExpirationCell_ordered` otherwise it pivoted duplicate `StrikeCell`s and `ExpirationCell`s. Doing that worked. Thank you!

Comment: @strimp099 Right, I forgot about duplicates.